# How to get count and avg of results in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the below query returning all available fiction books from all libraries:

```
$results = Library::with('category.books')
    ->whereHas('category.books', function($query) {
        $query->where('available', 1);
    })
    ->whereHas('category', function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'fiction');
    })
    ->get();
```

Now, what is the best way to get the total number of books and the average rating per book (book has field `rating`), per library?

I assume I have to create a collection of these results somehow, apply a custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the libraries while made changes to them using `map()` function.

You can count number of items in the collection using `count()` function.

You can get average by a property of items in the collection using `average()` function.

```php
$libraries = $results->map(function($library) {

    // All the books of the library
    $books = $library->category->flatMap->books;

    // set book count and average rating to the library object
    $library->book_count = $books->count();
    $library->average_rating = $books->average('rating');

    return $library;
});
```

Now every library object in this `$libraries` collection has those new two properties called `book_count` and `average_rating`.

Comment: Deleted my answer.  This is so clean and you taught me something with `flatMap`.  Nice.

Comment: In above code, I assume `$result->` needs to be `$library->`?

Comment: Nope. Its the result you have already fetched. The exact code you have posted in the question.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Got it, but needs to be plural `$results->` instead of `$result->`

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved in a number of ways. From the results that you have:

```
$libraries = Library::with('category.books')
    ->whereHas('category.books', function($query) {
        $query->where('available', 1);
    })
    ->whereHas('category', function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'fiction');
    })
    ->get();

$books = $libraries->map(function ($library) {
    return $library->category->books;
})
->collapse()
->filter(); // This is an optional step to remove NULL books, if there are any.

$count = $books->count();

$avg = $books->avg('rating'); // Or $books->average('rating');
```

But I think a better approach could be calculating the count and average from a query starting from Book, let's define a relationship named category in the model class if you haven't have one:

```
class Book
{
    // This could be a different type of relationships.
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('category');
    }
}
```

Then write a query.

```
$query = Book::where('available', 1) 
    ->whereHas('category', function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'fiction');
    });

$count = $query->count();
$avg = $query->avg(); // Or $query->average();
```

Comment: Wrong answer. He needs ( count and average ) per library, not all the books.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the relation in library model for count average of book and rating like below. I am expecting that you have a column library_id in books table.

```
In your library model. 

public function TotalBooks()
{  
    return $this->hasMany('App\Books', 'library_id')
        ->selectRaw('SUM(id) as total_book'); 
}

public function AvgRating()
    {  
        return $this->hasMany('App\Books', 'library_id')
            ->selectRaw('AVG(rating) as avg_arting');
    }

$data = Library::with('TotalBooks')->with('AvgRating');   // Get record
```